# Avoiding duplicate browser tabs or windows (window.open())

Tags: javascript, window, window.open

In Javascript, we can use window.open() to open a new browser window or tab.
But if a tab is already open, it should highlight that only. It should not open duplicate tabs.
How to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if window is already open window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138236/check-if-window-is-already-open-window-open)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [second argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open) of `window.open(strUrl, strWindowName[, strWindowFeatures]);` is the window name. if you specify that parameter, to anything other than "_blank" it will refer to the already opened tab/window.

For instance:

```
window.open('/about', 'newwindow');
```

and

```
window.open('/contact', 'newwindow');
```

will open the page in an already opened window/tab.

Comment: ya.. i did that... it worked.. but is there any way that it wont reload that page if it is already open? i just want to focus that...

Comment: You could try `newwin = window.open(...')` and `newwin.focus();` It works for popups but not tabs in firefox. In IE I think it defaults to opening new windows so it works.

Comment: I already did that. It is focusing but still it is reloading the window already present. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: you could do this `if (newwin != null) { newwin = window.open('...'); } else { newwin.focus(); }`

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you supply the same window name to window.open() every time! (second parameter, must not be empty)

You will need to manage the window object returned from window.open() and check if it was closed or not, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window and the `closed` property.  You will have to have a window to url list which will help you decide if to use window.open() to open a new window (a url which isn't open at the moment) or use the openedWindow.focus() (openedWindow is the object returned by the previous call to window.open()) to bring the window into view.

Comment: ya.. i did that... it worked..
but is there any way that it wont reload that page if it is already open? i just want to focus on that...

Answer (score 2):

Give the window a target name:
http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

New urls wil open in it if exist already

Answer (score 0):

Candide's code needs a slight correction. The null condition should be checked and not "!="

popwin.html is the page you want to open in a popup. I know this is already answered, just posting in case someone wanted to refer later on.

MAIN WINDOW CODE:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var newwin;
function popup(){

if (newwin == null) 
    { 
    window.open('popwin.html', 'newwin'); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    newwin.focus(); 
    }
}

</script>
```

CALL THE POPUP in body area of same page:

```
<a href="#" onClick="popup();">Open Window</a>
```