# Open .html page within same window only once. File run locally

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html file that will be run locally using IE. I want it to function more like an app, it will not be published to a site, I'm only using IE to view it. The code that follows will provide basic functions to do simple calculations. I've not been able to successfully use the window.onload event to create a new window that removes the scroll bar, title bar, menu, etc without it looping. I'm not sure if an If statement or a while statement is best for testing if the page is already open to stop the loop and I'm having a hard time understanding the syntax of how to test if the window.onload already has the window open. I guess I'm looking for some guidance on setting this up or a reference easily understood by a beginner. Thank you.

I at present have two html files. The first, its only purpose in life is to trigger the second to load as I want it to show.

```
function openWindow() 
        {           
            window.open("CouchShifts.html", "", "status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,navigationbar=no,location=no,resizable=no,scrollbars=n, width=440,height=200'");
        }
        window.onload = openWindow()
        window.close("test.html")
```

I had tried to incorporate this idea into the original html file without success. Any starts on how to better handle this so that when the standalone html file is double clicked from the desk top it open as specified above only once without looping?

Answer (score 0):

It's not wise to check window is open or not in the same windows onLoad. You should check it rather in the event that actually opens the window.

Here are some solutions for this.

[Check if window is already open window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138236/check-if-window-is-already-open-window-open)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10467344/672455