# Javascript - Prevent window refresh when use focus

Tags: javascript

I have to implement the next requirement: From a specified page I have to open a new page (new browser tab, lets call it *Live tab*) and focus on it. **Only one *Live tab* can be opened at a time**

What I've tried is

```
const win = this.window.open(url, 'New tab');
win?.focus();
```

This is working as expected but if the *Live tab* is already opened, the **focus** operation triggers a refresh of the *Live tab* every time.

Can we prevent this somehow ?

Comment: This answer explains it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25963141/window-focus-without-refresh-in-javascript

Comment: It's not the focus operation that causes it to refresh, it's caused by opening the url in the already opened window

Comment: You can keep a reference to the pop up, but once the page that opens up the pop up is destroyed, you will not be able to reference that pop up. Basically you will not be able to handle every edge case.