# Javascript - How to check if window.open(url) is successful?

Tags: javascript

How to check the status and/or wait until a successful connection of a `window.open()`? (Or suggest better alternatives)

```
var url = 'https://www.google.com';
var newWindow = window.open(url, 'main');

if(newWindow == 'success'){ //url was successfully opened
    ...
}
else { //url returned 404
    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your query ? [Check if window is already open window.open](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12138236/15405352)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated on MDN's [`Window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) page:

> **Return value**
>
> A `WindowProxy` object, which is basically a thin wrapper for the `Window` object representing the newly created window,
> and has all its features available. If the window couldn't be opened,
> the returned value is instead `null`.

So, it suffices to check for `null`:

```js
var url = 'https://www.google.com';
var newWindow = window.open(url, 'main');

if (newWindow == null) {
  // Failed
} else {
  // Success
}
```

A window being successfully opened doesn't give you information about the HTTP response status of the URL loaded in that window though.

Comment: How would I get the HTTP response status? That's what I'm looking for!

Comment: You're probably better off sending an AJAX request and check the response code of that before calling `Window.open()`.

Comment: Using the ajax request method. Thank you