# How to open HTML in only one Window/Tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

What I want to do -

> 1) On Click of a button I will open a new window(popup).
>
> 2) When I
>   click on same button, If the window(popup)is already open I will not
>   open it again instead bring the previously opened window(popup) on top
>   of all windows.
>
> 3) If popup is not open I will use window.open() to open a popup.

What I did till now -

> 1) On Click of a button I will open a new window(popup).
>
> 2) *Problem* : How do I not allow opening of new window on click of button if window is already open?

Comment: and where is the code??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoiding duplicate browser tabs or windows (window.open())](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496345/avoiding-duplicate-browser-tabs-or-windows-window-open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

Javascript function:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}
</script>
```

HTML tag:

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

Source: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html
Please take a look at the source for this and how they got it to work. They do also have some examples of exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Please take window.open() in one variable like

var w=  window.open();
It will not open new window again.

Good Luck.